# Is Wicket a suitable Web java framework for Single Page Applications?

Tags: java, scala, web-applications, wicket, single-page-application

Or there are best options (frameworks) for this kind of application, SPA?

I'm interested in use only Scala or Java frameworks for backend development.

And the mainly important points for choose a backend web framework for me are:

- good documentation, resources and many examples
- maturity and large adoption by the community and with considerable real use cases.
- a easy and short learn curve.
- a simple and extensive architecture that make easy use or add features like authentication, authorization and others common needed in a web app.

Comment: Did you consider the Play Framework? It is stateless (while Wicket manages state on the server), which may be an advantage, depending on your use case.

Comment: This question can not be answered with facts, any response you might get will be very subjective. I suggest you simply check your points with some frameworks, [this wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_application_frameworks#Java_2) might be a good starting point.

Comment: Yes, wicket can be used for single page apps. However, I wouldn't say that the learning curve is gradual, nor that the architecture is simple. Have you considered writing all your UI code in say javascript with a simple rest api on the server?

Comment: I really don't understand how people determine what is 'constructive'. The question wasn't even about 'what framework is better', but 'is this one suitable for this particular task?' (a perfectly reasonable question IMHO). meh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can build a SPA with Wicket, and its component architecture actually makes it very simple.

Basically, what would be a page in an usual application, you turn into a Panel, and make the single page switch panels with Ajax instead of navigating between pages. You can use multiple panels for multiple sections of the page, etc. All this is very simple and natural with the framework. The event architecture, added since 5.x, makes it even simpler to use inter-section communication.

The one thing you lose, though, is bookmark-ability of pages.

Since it's a single page, the URL in the browser's address bar won't ever change, and if the user creates a bookmark, it will always hit the initial page, not the page shown when the bookmark was made.

Client-side (javascript-based) frameworks (like GWT) usually implement this by using dynamic anchors (the string in the URL after #) to encode the current state, so that the app can reconstruct it if needed, but being a server-centric framework, Wicket can't do it (at least, not without much custom code). Possible, doable, but will require some thought and work.

Many times this isn't a required feature (or may even be an undesirable behaviour). If that is the case, Wicket can really help you.

About using action-based frameworks (Struts, Spring MVC, Play, etc.), they are more appropriate if you want a client-heavy architecture. But you'll inevitably code most of your application in Javascript, or using some Java-to-javascript-compiler (GWT), and use the framework just to make the queries, I mean, implement the services (XML, JSON, or some variant).