# How can Apache Wicket be used to make a single page web app?

Tags: wicket

I am trying to understand what kind of web applications Apache Wicket is suitable for, and it seems to be page based from what I have seen. How can it be used to make single page web apps as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14925177/176897

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At our company we have 3 SPA built on Wicket. They all work :) Basiclly our structure is:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div wicket;id="menu">
       <!-- navi links -->
    </div>
    <div wicket:id="main">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And we replace the `main` panel and it's inside panels effectivly getting an SPA.
Ajax support in Wicket 6 is very good.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its basically for page based webapps. So, it can also be used easily form single page web app.

I suggest just reading this short example of [Hello world](http://wicket.apache.org/learn/examples/helloworld.html)

After that, you can easily edit your equivalent of HelloWorld.html and HelloWorld.java to make really easy HTML in Java.